# Multiple Parameters in Less.Js

Tags: css, less

Can I use multiple parameters in a class? For instance I'd like to give a div both border radius and a background color. How would I do this?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
.button (@radius, @color) {
  border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
  background:@color;
}
```

Comment: http://designshack.co.uk/articles/css/using-less-js-to-simplify-your-css3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to separate them by commas.

```
.button (@radius 4px, @color #000) {
   border-radius: @radius;
   -moz-border-radius: @radius;
   -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
   background:@color;
}
```

Don't separate them by semi colons.